# Which user library versions should I use for: libnfnetlink and libnetfilter_queue?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, netfilter

Which version of netfilter user library modules should I use ?

I will be building the following modules for my application. The source will come from netfilter.org (and using there reference versions).
libmnl
libnfnetlink
libnetfilter_queue

OS: Linux 2.6.32

Comment: "OS: Linux 2.6.32" - This is NOT an **Operating System** specification. 2.6.32 is the version of the **Linux kernel**. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403938/whats-the-relationship-between-a-linux-os-and-a-kernel

Comment: OS: Montavista / Open Embedded mips64 GNU/Linux